# Where should $httpBackend.expect() go?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, httpbackend

The following test passes:

**admin.controller.js**

```
angular
  .module('mean-starter')
  .controller('AdminController', AdminController);

function AdminController(User, Auth, $state) {
  var vm = this;
  User
    .list()
    .success(function(data) {
      vm.users = data;
    })
    .error(function() {
      console.log('Problem getting users.');
    });

  vm.delete = function(id) {
    User
      .delete(id)
      .success(function(data) {
        if (Auth.getCurrentUser()._id === id) Auth.logout(); // deleting yourself
        else $state.reload();
      })
      .error(function() {
        console.log('Problem deleting user.');
      });
  };
}
```

**admin.controller.spec.js**

```
describe('AdminController', function() {
  var AdminController, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(module('mean-starter'));
  beforeEach(module('templates'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _$httpBackend_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    AdminController = $controller('AdminController');
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('gets users', function() {
    $httpBackend
      .expectGET('/users')
      .respond('foo');
    $httpBackend.flush();
  });
});
```

I wouldn't expect it to. Here is what I expected to happen:

1. The controller is instantiated in the `beforeEach`.
2. `User.list()` gets run.
3. The `$http` isn't yet overridden by `$httpBackend`, so the request goes out normally.
4. `$httpBackend.expectGET('/users').respond('foo')` expects `GET /users`. And says, "I'll respond with 'foo' if I get that request".
5. `$httpBackend.flush()` says "Send out the defined responses for any of the requests that `$httpBackend` received."
6. `.expectGET` fails because it doesn't receive it's request (the request happened before the expectation).
7. `.flush()` throws an error because there's nothing to flush.

I'm not getting the outcomes I was expecting, so something about my logic above must be wrong - what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The $http isn't yet overridden by $httpBackend, so the request goes out normally.

This is not a correct assumption. `$httpBackend` is used automatically in unit tests (it's part of the ng-mocks module that's used in unit tests). So whether you use $httpBackend or not in your unit test code, it's there and it's processing all the $http requests that your code makes.

Think about it, if it wasn't doing this, your unit tests could make real requests.

**EDIT**

For cases like this, where the controller is making an HTTP request as soon as it's instantiated, I like to put the `$httpBackend.expectGET()` call in the `beforeEach` block right before you instantiate the controller.

I would also `flush()` the backend in the `beforeEach` block as well. This, I think, makes it clear that these requests happen at controller startup. And it means I don't have to make this expectation in every unit test.